# how to remove additional borders from a tabular image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

is there any method that can remove lines from a tabular image
for example removing those in upper lines :

[image: input]

to match this output :

[image: output]

Comment: can't you simply crop image? Computer is not so clever to read in your mind or guess what you want to remove. You have to some how define what you want to remove. All above horizontal line? So you would have to find all horizontal lines and get line with the smallest Y and then crop all with smaller Y.

Comment: Remove all lines using morphology, then redraw them as you would like. Or use Hough transform to get the lines and limit them to the intersections.

Comment: For **this specific image**, there's a very simple solution using `np.sum` for example. But, what do your other images look like? Also, what have YOU tried so far? Please show existing code you have.

Comment: thank you all, indeed the main idea of this project is to concatenate two tables after removing headers using a snipping tool, the gap you see, is due to the snipping tool which is not specific